# Linux kernel page freeing

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel

I'm building my own memory pool as a Linux kernel module. I modified page frame allocation function so that user level processes get page frames from my memory pool. This works fine. Then I tried to modify the page freeing function in order to reclaim page frames when they are freed by processes. But whenever I enabled page reclaiming, I couldn't start any program, with "segmentation fault" message printed in console.

I'm using `alloc_page(__GFP_HIGHMEM | __GFP_MOVABLE | __GFP_ZERO)` to create my memory pool, which goes into per-cpu page frame cache, so every page I get has a usage counter (page->_count) set to 1.

For page freeing, I inserted a few lines in `free_pcppages_bulk()`, which is called when per-cpu page frame cache wants to flush some free pages back to Buddy system:

```
static void free_pcppages_bulk(struct zone *zone, int count, 
    struct per_cpu_pages *pcp)
{
int migratetype = 0;
int batch_free = 0;
int to_free = count;

spin_lock(&zone->lock);
zone_clear_flag(zone, ZONE_ALL_UNRECLAIMABLE);
zone->pages_scanned = 0;

while (to_free) {
    struct page *page;
    struct list_head *list;

    /*
     * Remove pages from lists in a round-robin fashion. A
     * batch_free count is maintained that is incremented when an
     * empty list is encountered.  This is so more pages are freed
     * off fuller lists instead of spinning excessively around empty
     * lists
     */
    do {
        batch_free++;
        if (++migratetype == MIGRATE_PCPTYPES)
            migratetype = 0;
        list = &pcp->lists[migratetype];
    } while (list_empty(list));

    do {
        page = list_entry(list->prev, struct page, lru);
        /* must delete as __free_one_page list manipulates */
        list_del(&page->lru);
        /* MIGRATE_MOVABLE list may include MIGRATE_RESERVEs */

        /* --ADDED BY ME-- */
        if(colored_free != NULL) { /* if my memory pool is created */
            if(!colored_free(page, zone)) { /* if it fails, free page to Buddy system */
                __free_one_page(page, zone, 0, page_private(page));
            }
        }
        else {
            __free_one_page(page, zone, 0, page_private(page));
        }

        trace_mm_page_pcpu_drain(page, 0, page_private(page));
    } while (--to_free && --batch_free && !list_empty(list));
}
__mod_zone_page_state(zone, NR_FREE_PAGES, count);
spin_unlock(&zone->lock);
}
```

In `colored_free()`, I simply insert the page descriptor in a page free list. Since the page usage counter is set to 0 when it's going to be freed to Buddy system, I reset it to 1 to restore the initial page state when my memory pool is created.

Any suggestion on this? Or is there a better way to free page frames to my memory pool instead of Buddy system?